# H2 add/subtract Interval Second in Oracle Query

Tags: java, oracle, h2, intervals

I have h2 database in server mode for my tests.

I can't add/subtract an interval to my date, in my spring-batch writer, when my request works in SQLDeveloper

h2 config :

```
private DataSource createH2DataSource() {
    String jdbcUrl = String.format("jdbc:h2:%s/target/db/h2;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;MODE=Oracle", System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource();
    ds.setURL(jdbcUrl);
    ds.setUser("sa");
    ds.setPassword("");

    return ds;
}
```

liquibase :

```
<column name="DATE_DEBUT_BI" type="TIMESTAMP" />
<column name="DATE_FIN_BI" type="TIMESTAMP" />
```

my request :

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET DATE_FIN_BI = :dateFinBi - INTERVAL '1' SECOND WHERE DATE_J = :dateJ AND CODE_EDE = :codeEde AND STATUT_EFFACEMENT = :statutEffacement
```

Error :

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE MY_TABLE  SET DATE_FIN_BI = ? - INTERVAL '1' SECOND WHERE DATE_J = ? AND CODE_EDE = ? AND STATUT_EFFACEMENT = ?]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "UPDATE MY_TABLE  SET DATE_FIN_BI = ? - INTERVAL '1'[*] SECOND WHERE DATE_J = ? AND CODE_EDE = ? AND STATUT_EFFACEMENT = ?"; SQL statement:
UPDATE MY_TABLE  SET DATE_FIN_BI = ? - INTERVAL '1' SECOND WHERE DATE_J = ? AND CODE_EDE = ? AND STATUT_EFFACEMENT = ? [42000-196]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:662)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:950)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.executeBatchUpdateWithNamedParameters(NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.java:40)
...
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "UPDATE MY_TABLE  SET DATE_FIN_BI = ? - INTERVAL '1'[*] SECOND WHERE DATE_J = ? AND CODE_EDE = ? AND STATUT_EFFACEMENT = ?"; SQL statement:
UPDATE MY_TABLE  SET DATE_FIN_BI = ? - INTERVAL '1' SECOND WHERE DATE_J = ? AND CODE_EDE = ? AND STATUT_EFFACEMENT = ? [42000-196]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:191)
at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:534)
at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:261)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:578)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:519)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1204)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1524)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:627)
... 36 more
```

"Solution" :

Thanks guys, so i extracted the subtract in java to have a simple query.

Comment: Should it not be `1 SECOND` rather than `'1' SECOND`?

Comment: @JoopEggen same error without ''

Comment: @STaefi `[*]` is a marker for the spot of the error.

Comment: `INTERVAL '1 SECOND'` I think I saw somewhere.

Comment: @JoopEggen Same thing :(

Comment: Maybe h2 has problem with INTERVAL literals. Try `TO_DSINTERVAL('0 00:00:01')` or `NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'SECOND')`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Both work in SQL Developer, but not with h2. error : Function "TO_DSINTERVAL" not found; Function "NUMTODSINTERVAL" not found.  
I specified MODE=Oracle in h2 url, is sufficient ?

Comment: DATEADD('SECOND', -1, :dateDebutBi) works, but not in Oracle ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i extracted the subtract in java to have a simple query.
For that, I used the ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider from JdbcItemWriter

```
ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<NebefEffEdePdh> itemSqlParameter = nebefEffEdePdh -> new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("dateDebutBiMoins1Second",Utils.getDateMinusSeconds(nebefEffEdePdh.getDateDebutBi(), DELTA_DATE_DEBUT_FIN_BI))
            .addValue("dateJ", nebefEffEdePdh.getDateJ())
            .addValue("codeEde", nebefEffEdePdh.getCodeEde())
            .addValue("statutEffacement", nebefEffEdePdh.getStatutEffacement());
writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(itemSqlParameter);
```

My request :

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE  SET DATE_FIN_BI = :dateDebutBiMoins1Second WHERE TRUNC(DATE_J) = TRUNC(:dateJ) AND CODE_EDE = :codeEde AND STATUT_EFFACEMENT = :statutEffacement AND DATE_FIN_BI IS NULL
```